# Building octave from source - did ATLAS get included properly in Octaves ./configure script?

Tags: octave, configure, atlas

I'm building Octave from sources in order to include the ATLAS libraries. Did I get them included correctly? I don't know what to expect from the Octave configure script. I find "-llapack" suspiciously generic.

`./configure --with-lapack=/usr/local/atlas`

```
  Source directory:            .
  Installation prefix:         /usr/local
  C compiler:                  gcc   -Wall -W -Wshadow -Wformat -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -g -O2 -pthread
  C++ compiler:                g++   -Wall -W -Wshadow -Wold-style-cast -Wformat -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -g -O2 -pthread
  Fortran compiler:            gfortran -O
  Fortran libraries:            -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath
  Lex libraries:               
  LIBS:                        -lutil -lm  
  ...
  HDF5 libraries:              -lhdf5
  Java home:                   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
  Java JVM path:               /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server
  Java CPPFLAGS:               -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
  Java libraries:              
  LAPACK libraries:            -llapack
  LLVM CPPFLAGS:               
  LLVM LDFLAGS:                
  LLVM libraries:              
  Magick++ CPPFLAGS:           -I/usr/include/GraphicsMagick  
  Magick++ LDFLAGS:             
  Magick++ libraries:          -lGraphicsMagick++ -lGraphicsMagick  
  ...
```

`allusers@vbubuntu:~/Downloads/octave-3.8.1$ ll -R /usr/local/atlas/`

```
/usr/local/atlas/:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 May 25 23:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 May 25 23:01 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May 25 23:01 include/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May 25 23:01 lib/

/usr/local/atlas/include:
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 May 25 23:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 May 25 23:01 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 May 25 23:01 atlas/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 33962 May 25 23:06 cblas.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9708 May 25 23:06 clapack.h

/usr/local/atlas/include/atlas:
total 604
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 May 25 23:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 May 25 23:01 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2089 May 25 23:06 atlas_buildinfo.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    90 May 25 23:06 atlas_cacheedge.h
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2716 May 25 23:06 zmm.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   552 May 25 23:06 zXover.h

/usr/local/atlas/lib:
total 26548
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 May 25 23:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 May 25 23:01 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14165306 May 25 23:06 libatlas.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   455844 May 25 23:06 libcblas.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   572392 May 25 23:06 libf77blas.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10942494 May 25 23:06 liblapack.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   456426 May 25 23:06 libptcblas.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   572788 May 25 23:06 libptf77blas.a
allusers@vbubuntu:~/Downloads/octave-3.8.1$
```

---

Additional info:

After spamming echo statements in the config file I've noticed the following:

This line:

```
$as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for $cheev in $LAPACK_LIBS" >&5
```

has the correct $LAPACK_LIBS variable in it (the one I passed in). It's this line that appears to be the first failure to find something in the lapack libraries I'm telling it about:

```
if ac_fn_c_try_link "$LINENO"; then :
```

Just before that line I see the config file define some c code that I believe it's running to identify whether whatever 'cheeve' is, is found in the libraries.

```
checking for cheev_ in /usr/local/atlas/lib/... no
checking for cheev_... no
checking for cheev_ in -llapack... yes
```

configuration script

```
cat confdefs.h - <<_ACEOF >conftest.$ac_ext
/* end confdefs.h.  */

/* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
   Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
   builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
char $cheev ();
#ifdef F77_DUMMY_MAIN

#  ifdef __cplusplus
     extern "C"
#  endif
   int F77_DUMMY_MAIN() { return 1; }

#endif
int
main ()
{
return $cheev ();
  ;
  return 0;
}
_ACEOF
```

At this point the C code has gone beyond my comprehension level. It seems like it has something to do with whether the F77 compiler (compiler translator??) is being invoked or not.

Comment: Build it and see if everything goes fine. You can see at least `-llapack` is enabled.

Comment: I built it, but I presume it's using the default lapack libraries (e.g. single threaded) since when I do a large matrix multiplication operation I still only see a single thread working. I don't actually even know how to validate that it's using the ATLAS libraries vs. some other libraries it found. I previously had octave installed from the Ubuntu package manager, so I presume the default standard libraries are also available on the system somewhere.

Comment: Grep the build log to see if you can find `/usr/local/atlas` somewhere.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the process to find the "build log", can you direct me to what I'm looking for here? I'm on an Ubuntu system. Don't see anything in the directory where I run make & configure, and I don't see something obvious in /var/logs. Is that generated by `configure` or by `make`?

Comment: Sure. First run `make clean` and then `make 2>&1 | tee build.log`. This will generate the file `build.log` for you to grep "atlas".

Comment: Ah, just the terminal output, yeah, I see 8 references to ATLAS, all similar to this, but I don't think these are the silver bullet: Overfull \hbox (8.96994pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 194--199
 \@textrm cel-er-ated \@textsc blas @textrm li-braries such as AT-LAS ([][]@textt
t http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net[][][]@textrm )|
[834]

Comment: I guess your ATLAS is not being used, otherwise `-L/usr/local/atlas` would appear somewhere. Try grep `libatlas`, `liblapack`, etc. Also try running `./configure --with-lapack=/usr/local/atlas/lib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think I worked this out after a marathon debugging session.

Octave doesn't appear to recognize the atlas libraries unless they're in shared format (.so files not the .a files that are generated by default).

When I build ATLAS with the `--shared` option added, and I reference the .so files generated by ATLAS, the Octave config script accepts them. Note: Make sure you use libtatlas.so, not libsatlas.so, assuming you want the multithreaded libraries.

Reference material:

ATLAS ./configure arguments:

```
../configure --shared -b 64 -D c -DPentiumCPS=3000 --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=/home/allusers/Downloads/lapack-3.5.0.tgz
```

Octave ./configure arguments:

```
./configure --with-lapack=/usr/local/atlas/lib/libtatlas.so --with-blas=/usr/local/atlas/lib/libtatlas.so
```

Expected Octave `./configure` output:

```
...
BLAS libraries:              /usr/local/atlas/lib/libtatlas.so
...
LAPACK libraries:            /usr/local/atlas/lib/libtatlas.so
...
```

Incorrect Octave `./configure` output:

```
...
BLAS libraries:              -lblas
...
LAPACK libraries:            -llapack
...
```

My full build process for ATLAS and Octave:

```
ATLAS setup:
    bunzip2 -c atlas3.10.x.tar.bz2 | tar xfm -
    mv ATLAS atlas3.10.1
    cd atlas3.10.1
    mkdir build_vbubuntu
    cd build_vbubuntu
    sudo apt-get install gfortran f2c libcnf-dev            # ???
    ../configure --shared -b 64 -D c -DPentiumCPS=3000 --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=/home/allusers/Downloads/lapack-3.5.0.tgz
    make build
    make check      # test serial routines
    make ptcheck    # check parallel routines
    make time
    sudo make install

Octave setup:
    sudo apt-get build-dep octave
    ./configure --with-lapack=/usr/local/atlas/lib/libtatlas.so --with-blas=/usr/local/atlas/lib/libtatlas.so
    sudo make install
```

Full disclosure: While I've written up this answer because I got octave to admit that the atlas libraries exist (and I don't want to forget to write it later), the end result is still not working, a large scale matrix multiplication doesn't use multiple cores. Hence, if the cause of that issue is related I may be back to edit this answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

My successful attempt to compile octave (3.8.2) on CENTOS including atlas:
(make sure to remove blas-devel and lapack-devel, just in case)

```
> yum install atlas-sse3.x86_64
> setenv LDFLAGS -L/usr/lib64/atlas-sse3
>./configure --with-lapack=-latlas --with-blas=-latlas --enable-jit
> make -j20
(as root)> make install

After configure you should see:
    BLAS libraries:              -lcblas -lf77blas -latlas
    LAPACK libraries:            -llapack
```